# What can happen on double commit in github?

Tags: github, commit

I have the following situation. I was developing and I needed to deploy, on live, a commit  from a while ago, let's call it `commit1`, but it was between other commits which I didn't want to be live. So I made a new brach and I cherry picked that commit so I can push only that one to live.

Now my question is:

When I will push another branch to live , that already has that `commit1` in it, something like double commit will happen? can something go wrong in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would rebase your branch first, on top of the live branch.

The rebase process will detect the duplicated commit, and will *not* replay it (ie, it will be dropped) during the rebase of your commits on top of live.
Once the rebase isdone, you can push and deploy from your (rebased) branch.